# How do I download a file from a local folder

Tags: sitecore-client

I read data from mongodb and export it to .csv, then save it to my local folder (file path ="F:\report.csv").

When I click the download button in the Sitecore interface it should be downloaded from the local file path. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you have some user interface from which you generate the report? Like a custom page?

Comment: I was Implemented new button(export) sitecore interface.when i click the export button it should be read,save the data into local then it should be downloaded. data stored successfully in local but its not downloading.

Comment: Did you use Sheer UI to implement the button? Or SPEAK? Where is the button located? Is it in the ribbon in the Content Editor?

Comment: button was located in Ribbon/chunks

Comment: I think the question as it stands right now, needs a lot of clarification. Could you elaborate a bit on what it is, more specifically, you have done (with relevant code and config snippets)?  That way, answering the question doesn't become a guessing contest, but rather constructive feedback to your approach and how to achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 5):

With that assumption that you are triggering an implementation of a Sitecore Command (by inheriting from `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Command`), you can trigger a download in the Content Editor using the `SheerResponse` utility class:

```cs
SheerResponse.Download(localPathToYourFile);
```

Comment: its not working.it shows "The process cannot access the file 'F:\report.csv' because it is being used by another process."

Comment: This is likely because you are trying to send the file because you haven't closed it after wring it. Either way, could you follow the advice of the comments on the question and expand your question to be clearer of the situation? Note that there are several Sitecore interfaces - e.g. the content editor, experience editor - so you should state what one this is in.

Comment: I have an csv file in my local folder(F:\report.csv).so how to download the file from that path using c#?